# Mysql - Where IN clause not select data properly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

i have comma separated string with single quote

1. `select * from  demoProject WHERE id IN(1,2,3);`
2. `set @ids := "'1,2,3'"; select * from  demoProject WHERE id IN(@ids)`

First query works fine but second query only fetch data with associated id '1'. Where am I wrong with second query?

Comment: put all values in single quotes respectively like'1','2'

Comment: You are searching for a string, 1 OR 2 OR 3 is not equal to  string '1,2,3'

Comment: @nic Whenever you have performance issues with the currently accepted answer, have a look at mine. He should have stated, that with his solution an index can not be used. With mine that's not the case. That's what I actually meant with "the only way".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you insert a STRING into IN statement so you get condition: `id IN('1,2,3')`. You should use a dynamic sql in this case.

Also in MySQL you can use [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function to find number in a comma separated STRING. So it can help here:

```
set @ids := "'1,2,3'"; select * from  demoProject WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id,@ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change your id's from

```
set @ids := "'1,2,3'";
```

to

```
set @ids := "'1','2','3'";
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work, because `@ids` is treated as a string. The implicit conversion to integer will get you always just the first number.

The only way to make this work, is to use prepared statements (which have to be used in a stored procedure in this case):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_prep_stmt(IN ids int)
BEGIN
SET @sql = 'select * from demoProject WHERE id IN(?);';
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt USING ids;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then execute the procedure with

```
CALL sp_prep_stmt('1, 2, 3');
```